# Iterate through set of dictionaries - python - basic search

Tags: python, search, set, dictionary

I have a really weird thing happening.  I am trying to loop through a set of dictionaries to find all of the items with a specific value related to a field key.  Take the following:

ex_set is an output from a mysql system that I do not have control over.  If I had to re-create it using python, it would be something like:

```
dict_a [ 'field' ] = 'fruit'
dict_a [ 'value' ] = 'apple'
dict_b [ 'field' ] = 'fruit'
dict_b [ 'value' ] = 'berry'
ex_set = set()
ex_set.add (dict_a,dict_b)
```

The important thing is how the set looks when I pprint it.

```
pprint (ex_set)
OUTPUTS> ({'field' : 'fruit',
        'value' : 'apple'},
        'field' : 'fruit'},
        'value' : 'berry'})

i = 0
while len ( ex_set ) > i:
    for k , v in ex_set [i].iteritems ( ):
        if v == 'fruit':
        pprint ( ex_set[i] )
    i += 1
```

The problem is that the printing of this does not print all of the dictionaries that have a value = "fruit".

Is there a better way to search through a set of dictionaries?  The set that I am searching through has 3 key/value combinations in each dictionary and about 30k dictionaries.  This works about 25% of the time and I can't figure out why it is only returning about 20% of the matches.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: post a better example, the `ex_set` is invalid python.

Comment: this can't be the actual code...because it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description you are seeking something like:

```
In [6]: ex_set = ({'fruit':'apple',
   ...:            'value':'fruit'},
   ...:           {'fruit':'fruit'},
   ...:           {'apple':'apple'})

In [7]: for d in ex_set:
   ...:     if 'fruit' in d.values():
   ...:         print(d)
   ...:         
{'fruit': 'apple', 'value': 'fruit'}
{'fruit': 'fruit'}
```

Also, in addition to the fact, that your example isn't valid python, ex_set certainly can't be a `set`, as `sets's` cant contain `dictionaries` as they are unhashable. I would consider renaming it to something more suitable:

```
In [8]: set([{}])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-7facc835553f> in <module>()
----> 1 set([{}])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: Thanks.  The d.values is really what I was looking for.

Comment: `sets's cant contain dictionaries as they are unhashable`: kinda not correct. If you have `di={1:'one',2:'two'}` you can do `set(di)`. It will create a set from the keys of the dict. `set(di)==set(dickeys())` is True.

Comment: @drewk -- well how is it incorrect, as it will be a set of values not a set of dict's. You can't have a set containing dict's.

Comment: @root: It is not a set containing a dict. It is a set of the hashable values of the dict's keys. By definition, a dict's keys are hashable. Try the code!  `>>> di={1:'one',2:'two'}; set(di)==set(di.keys())` That will print `True`   Also try `>>> set({1:'one',2:'two'})` which will print `{1, 2}`

Comment: @drewk -- your examples are all correct, but the OP was saying that he had a set of dict's that is not possible. I was only stating that you can't have a set that contains dict's not that you can't convert a dict to a set, containing it's keys. These all two separate issues.